# java.net.http package can't be resolved in android kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, java-http-client

I'm working on an simple android kotlin project which use the build-in java.net.http.HttpClient to make http post request, but it always failed to build, the error is:

```
Unresolved reference: http
Unresolved reference: HttpClient
Unresolved reference: HttpRequest
Unresolved reference: HttpResponse
```

settings in `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
}
```

The gradle JDK location and my `JAVA_HOME` variable point to the same environment which is the build-in version 11.0.3 under `my-android-studio-path/jre`

PS: I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511362/gradle-build-cant-find-the-package-java-net-http) before I post but unfortuntely it did not help, I don't know if there's something I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sources: [How can I use JDK 11 HTTP packages in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750452/how-can-i-use-jdk-11-http-packages-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Using Java 11 libraries on Android Kotlin projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363995/using-java-11-libraries-on-android-kotlin-projects))

> increasing the language level is of no use in this case as the used classes like java.net.http.HttpClient are simply not available on Android